# Add mailto functionality in admin field

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, adminhtml

How can i new field in admin filed that contain mailto functionality

```
$fieldset->addField('email', 'link', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('mumodule')->__('Email'),
    "target"=>"_blank",
    'mailto' => Mage::registry('mumodule')->getData('email'),
    'class'     => 'required-entry',
    'required'  => true,
    'name'      => 'title',
    ));
```

using this way i cant add functionality.

is it possible to add new filed with mailto functionality?

Comment: What do you mean by "mailto functionality"?

Comment: means when click on email it use to mailto functionality of php function by the way i achieve answer,,thanks for comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to do is create a `mailto:` link? In which case, the `mailto:` is part of the URL so it should be assigned in the `href` attribute:

```
$fieldset->addField('email', 'link', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('mumodule')->__('Email'),
    'target'    => '_blank',
    'href'      => 'mailto:' . urlencode(Mage::registry('mumodule')->getData('email')),
    'class'     => 'required-entry',
));
```